# XAMARIN: How to Refresh WebView OnTabReselected?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

I'm trying to refresh a WebView when the user reselects a tab that is already selected on Android coding with Xamarin using deprecated Actionbar and TabHost.

I've got this code

```
    public void OnTabReselected(WhatsOnActivity tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        WebView whatsOnWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);
        //tell webview to reload
        whatsOnWebView.Reload();
    }
```

and I've tried to put that code into both my MainActivity and inside My WhatsOnActivity

It doesn't crash the app, but it also doesn't reload the tab.  In Xamarin, can I use the "WhatsOnActivity" as the tab in my method?  I have a feeling that's what I'm doing wrong.. but if I try to use tab ids, they're not recognized by the IDE.  Can anyone give me direction on what I've done wrong?

my complete code can be found here:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_a2/blob/2.68/MainActivity.cs

if you're wondering about the context.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try to set `OnClicklistener` on your first tab. Set the listener after you add tabs.

```
 TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(0).SetOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(tabHost));
```

And the listener:

```
    public class MyOnClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
    {
        TabHost tabHost;
        public MyOnClickListener(TabHost tabHost)
        {
            this.tabHost = tabHost;
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {

            var parentView = ((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)tabHost.GetChildAt(0)).GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(0);
            WebView whatsOnWebView = parentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);
            whatsOnWebView.Reload();
            tabHost.CurrentTab = 0;
        }
    }
```

And the result is:

[image]

**Original answer**

Please try to add an `OnTabChangeListener` to your `TabHost`.

For example, In your MainActivity `OnCreate()`:

```
        TabHost tabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
        tabHost.SetOnTabChangedListener(new MyOnTabChangedListener(tabHost));
```

And the `MyOnTabChangedListener`:

```
    public class MyOnTabChangedListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnTabChangeListener
    {
        TabHost tabHost;
        public MyOnTabChangedListener(TabHost tabHost)
        {
            this.tabHost = tabHost;
        }

        public void OnTabChanged(string tabId)
        {
            if(tabId == "whats_on")
            {
                var parentView = ((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)tabHost.GetChildAt(0)).GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(0);                    
                WebView whatsOnWebView = parentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);
                whatsOnWebView.Reload();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I've added those suggestions into the project but getting exception cannot convert from com.xamarin.example.BitChute.MainActivity.MyOnTabChangedListener to Android.Widget.TabHost.IOnTabChangeListener

Comment: and also, the type or namespace IOnTabChangeListener could not be found.  I'm not sure why that class isn't within the scope of that method.  They're both inside my MainActivity... either way... I appreciate the tips =] and I'll use this advice as a base while I work out the syntax.

Comment: OK... so I added this assembly     using static Android.Widget.TabHost;

Comment: and now it's compiling fine and partially working... the problem is that if the tab is already selected it's still not reloading the WebView.  It only reloads the tab if I'm on another tab and then I reselect a tab that has already been loaded.  We're getting warmer tho...... =]  ...I'll look into checking to see if I can use an if statement for the page already being loaded and then reload accordingly.  thanks again man!

Comment: The problem is that code you have uses "OnTabChanged" whereas I need to invoke "OnTabReselected"

Comment: @hexagod `OnTabReselected` is a method in `OnTabSelectedListener`. And `OnTabSelectedListener` is a listener for `TabLayout` not `TabActivity`.

Comment: @hexagod Please try to set `OnClicklistener` on whats_on tab. I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: thank you so much @Billy Liu - MSFT !!!!! you helped me out so much!  works perfectly.  I have been searching for weeks how to do this.  Appreciate it more than you know =]  ... see you on bitchute

Comment: I tried to up-vote it but I don't have the rep to do so.

Comment: do you know how I can assign that code for a second tab?  I was able to get this working for the first tab but if I try to set for the second tab I'm getting object reference not set to instance of an object.  I've been toying around with this for about 12 hours but I can't seem to get it working for second tab.  I'll keep trying but if you see this, clue me in.  ty again =]

Comment: The weird thing is if I simply change the code to this I get object reference not set to an instance of an object... change it back to whatsOn it works fine...  am I using the GetChildAt wrong?  I looked online for more directions but still off                 var parentViewSubs = ((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)tabHost.GetChildAt(0)).GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(0);


                WebView subsWebView = parentViewSubs.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewSubs);


                subsWebView.Reload();
                

                tabHost.CurrentTab = 1;

Comment: I changed to this and now the subs reload when I press "whatsOn" .. lol... 

                      var parentViewSubs = ((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)tabHost.GetChildAt(0)).GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(1);


                WebView subsWebView = parentViewSubs.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewSubs);

                if (tabHost.CurrentTab == 1)
                {
                    subsWebView.Reload();
                }


                tabHost.CurrentTab = 1;

Comment: still working on this... your code is extremely close.  Just FYI though... the this.CurrentTab = 0; doesn't do anything.  It's not needed afaik.  the problem I'm having is that when I use the code above, it only reloads the second tab when I press the first one, if the second tab is already selected.  I've got the GetChildAt int wrong, but I'm not sure how the layout works in conjunction with those ints.

Comment: alright, so this line of code             TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(2).SetOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(tabHost));
 controls which tab the click listener is firing on.  However, when I set the int to 1 I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line of code                 WebView subWebView = parentViewSubs.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewSubs);

Comment: @hexagod You could try to use `tabHost.CurrentView` to find the view. `WebView webViewSubs = tabHost.CurrentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewSubs);` It will get null when this fired at change tab, and if it is reselected, it will not be null. `if (webViewSubs != null){                   webViewSubs.Reload(); }` If it helps, please help to mark as the answer.

Comment: I know what the problem is.  The click listener tries to reload the code every time a tab is clicked.  This works fine if the page is already loaded, which is why it works in your example, but app throws an exception when trying to reload a tab that hasn't loaded initially.  I think I need to set an propertynotificationchange for the onclick listener so that it only listens after the tab has been loaded initially

Comment: Billy I will definitely mark you as the answer once I get the details worked out.  You have already helped me out immensely.  Thank you! =]

Comment: I think I already tried that and the problem is that code intercepts the first click, and thus the code does nothing.  I tried to put loadurl into the block for when webViewSubs == null but got another object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to set the onclicklistener inside my Speakers (subscriptions) activity instead of inside the MainActivity ?  that way the first time the tab is selected, it loads the view but also sets the click listener?  I tried to do so but "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TabHost.TabWidget'" ,,, which is confusing to me because that same code does not have the compiler error when inside the scope of MainActivity

Comment: @hexagod In your Speakers activity OnCreate method: `TabHost tab = Parent.FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);((TabActivity)Parent).TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(1).SetOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(tab));`

Comment: I'll try that tonight.. can't test ATM but @Billy Liu - MSFT if I ever get this working you're definitely getting a massive shout-out in the creds!  =]

Comment: myyyy brrooooo BILLLLLLYYYYY YOURETHEMANNOWDOG.com  THANNNNNNKKKKKKK YOUUUU!!!! THAT WORKED!!! ... man I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: I tried to give you an up-vote for the rep but it won't let me homie (I don't have any rep so I can't give any).  You definitely deserve some credit for that one.  Thanks again.. stay in touch my dude

Answer (score 0):

First off thank you so much to @Billy Liu - MSFT !!! dude is a lifesaver.  He knows his Xamarin.  Alright, so here's how you can refresh a tab OnClick

//Assemblies

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Webkit;
using static Android.Widget.TabHost;
using static Android.Views.View;
using Android.Views;

//this assembly is your Activities class, which should contain your class instances
using com.xamarin.example.BitChute.Activities;
```

EDIT: Put these click listeners inside your MainActivity.cs .. the int inside GetChildAt() represents the tab our listener will respond to. int 0 = tab farthest left and they go up 0 .. 1 .. 2 .. etc .. 1 would mean tab second from the left.  Each listener will need it's own listener class instance.  I'll show two examples in the next block.

```
        TabHost tabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);

        tabHost.Setup();

        tabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(0).SetOnClickListener(new WhatsOnClickListener(tabHost));

        tabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(1).SetOnClickListener(new SubsClickListener(tabHost));

        tabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(2).SetOnClickListener(new DiscoverClickListener(tabHost));

        tabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(3).SetOnClickListener(new MyChannelClickListener(tabHost));

        tabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt(4).SetOnClickListener(new SettingsClickListener(tabHost));
```

EDIT: Create a separate ClickActivity.cs file and then add these listeners into it.  you will need to create an OnClickListener instance for each tab.  This example is only two of the listeners; but if you're using my template, you will need to use these examples to create another 3 listeners.

```
public class WhatsOnClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
{
    TabHost tabHost;

    //this int will tell the click listener whether to reload the webview or pop 2 root
    static int tbC = 0;

    public WhatsOnClickListener(TabHost tabHost)
    {
        //tell the clicklistener which tabhost to use
        this.tabHost = tabHost;
    }

    //this class handles the click event
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {

        //declare the webview and tell our object where to find the XAML resource
        WebView webViewWhatsOn = tabHost.CurrentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);

        //...if the CurrentTab != 0 ... we won't fire the Reload() or LoadUrl() 
        //..without this logic, the app will crash because our WebViews 
        //.aren't set to an instance of an object
        if (tabHost.CurrentTab == 0)
        {
            //if tbC int is 0, we will reload the page
            if (tbC == 0)
            {
                //tell whatsOnWebView to Reload
                webViewWhatsOn.Reload();

                //set the int to one so next time webview will pop to root
                tbC = 1;
            }
            //else if the int is 1, we will pop to root on tab 0
            else if (tbC == 1)
            {
                //tell whatsOnWebView to pop to root
                webViewWhatsOn.LoadUrl(@"https://bitchute.com/");

                //set the tbC int so that next time webview will reload
                tbC = 0;
            }
        }

        //if our current tab isn't zero, we need to set CurrentTab to 0
        //this line is critical or our tabs won't work when not selected
        tabHost.CurrentTab = 0;
    }
}

public class SubsClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
{
    TabHost tabHost1;

    static int tbC = 0;

    public SubsClickListener(TabHost tabHost1)
    {
        this.tabHost1 = tabHost1;
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (tabHost1.CurrentTab == 1)
        {

            WebView subWebView = tabHost1.CurrentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewSubs);

            if (tbC == 0)
            {
                subWebView.Reload();

                tbC = 1;
            }

            else if (tbC == 1)
            {
                subWebView.LoadUrl(@"https://bitchute.com/subscriptions/");

                tbC = 0;
            }
        }

        tabHost1.CurrentTab = 1;
    }
}
```

hope that helps!  I've been trying this for a minute.

Comment: This definitely works but it's got issues.  If another tab is selected then the app will crash or the tab does nothing.  I'll have to revise this.  There may be another way to do it.  the onclick tab method is useful, either way.  But I think I need to add another layer of logic that will load different URLs depending on the circumstances... will post more when I know more.

Comment: It actually might be better to handle the onclick method inside our mainactivity and then establish all of the connections there.  Problem is I kept getting null reference exceptions and object reference not set to instance of an object on the webviews when I put the references inside mainactivity

Comment: I've got another solution to this.. I'll post it later

Comment: fixed... @Billy Liu - MSFT helped me out big time... just had to add a bit of code to make it work.  This is a pretty good and complete answer IMO